# Disabled dropdownlist not working (autopostback & updatepanel related) C# asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, autopostback

After choosing a 2nd list item. The "Select Category..." for the 3rd drop down list is not disabled any more it became clickable/selectable.

The "Select Category..." should remain disabled in all drop down list.

I think it has something to do with Autopostback and UpdatePanel.
because I used updatepanel to keep the modal open when postingback and I used Autopostback to remove the selected item from drop down list.

This is my code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" runat="server">
 <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"  UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
           <div class="modal-body">

<div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" class="form-control" MaxLength="50" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" required >
                            <asp:ListItem Value="" disabled="disabled">Select Category...</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Artist/Curator</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>MCAD Exhibitor</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Student</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Collector/Buyer</asp:ListItem>

                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>


                           <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server" class="form-control" MaxLength="50" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl2_SelectedIndexChanged"  AutoPostBack="true" required >
                            <asp:ListItem Value="" disabled="disabled">Select Category...</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Artist/Curator</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>MCAD Exhibitor</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Student</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Collector/Buyer</asp:ListItem>

                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl3" runat="server" class="form-control" MaxLength="50" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl3_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" required >
                            <asp:ListItem Value="" disabled="disabled">Select Category...</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Artist/Curator</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>MCAD Exhibitor</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Student</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Collector/Buyer</asp:ListItem>

                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
</div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

My code behind .cs:

```
protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddl2.Items.Remove(ddl1.SelectedItem);
        ddl3.Items.Remove(ddl1.SelectedItem);

        UpdatePanel1.Update();


    }

    protected void ddl2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddl1.Items.Remove(ddl2.SelectedItem);
        ddl3.Items.Remove(ddl2.SelectedItem);

        UpdatePanel1.Update();



    }

    protected void ddl3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddl1.Items.Remove(ddl3.SelectedItem);
        ddl2.Items.Remove(ddl3.SelectedItem);

        UpdatePanel1.Update();

    }
```

Comment: Do you have any code in the Form_Load event that might reset the dropdowns?

Comment: @EricBurdo nope, i dont have any code inside the Page_Load

Answer (score 0):

This is not about your update panel(I tested). I think this is a bad behavior (or a bug) of drop down list that when you remove its item it select its first item and remove that disability. To solve this problem you can easily add this jquery to end of your codes:

```
  $('select').each(function ()
  {
       $(this).children().eq(0).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
```

And if you do not want to use jquery, paste this script after yout dropdowns:

```
<script>
  var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control');
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            console.log(arr[i]);
            arr[i].children[0].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
</script>
```

Comment: can you teach me on where should I put that code? also, when you tested that code it worked??

Comment: can you teach me on where should I put that code? also, when you tested that code it worked??

Comment: Yes i tested this. This must be after your dropdowns, And you must have an jquery link added to you page.

Comment: pls check this out if I did it right >> https://postimg.org/image/xuav4ggn3/

is that how supposed to be done? sorry i really dont know how to add jquery in my html code

I also have this code between <head>...</head> :
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: In the image i can not see the jquery link. I suggest you to use javascript code that i added to my answer.(instead of jquery).

Comment: this is **SOLVED** by using OnDataBound aside from SelectedIndexChanged :) ty xx